# Visual source safe check in for terminated employee

Tags: version-control, visual-sourcesafe

I have a coworker who was no longer work the same office.  He has checked out files in VSS.  How do I check in the item which checked out by him?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another thing you can do if the person has left or moved on is to delete their account with the admin tool and recreate it.

Then undo their checkouts (or check in, if you have access to their files) and delete their account again.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you can't just log on as him and check in the files.

One easy way would be to undo the checkout (you might have to use the admin tool for this) and then you checkout the files, copy over his changed files and check them in.

Actually, here's the MS support article about doing just this to solve your problem: [How To Resolve Files Checked Out by an Unavailable User](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/150648) (for version 4, 5 and 6, but I'm fairly sure it'll be exactly the same if you've got a later version, there wasn't any real GUI changes as far as I remember).

Comment: I did follow the step from MS support but couldn't do it.

Comment: @user79127: At what step does it fail?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "admin" to log in and undo the checkout.